# SQL: extract rows with different condition based on another column?

Tags: sql

Say you have a column labeled "Company", and a column labeled "Profit", and a column labeled 'Date'.

I then have a LIST of companies "Microsoft", "Ford", etc and a list of associated dates for each company, and all I want is the row for each company with the profit on the given date.

E.g. the list could be (Microsoft, Ford, Shell) for companies and (1st jan 2020, 3rd february 2020, 5th May, 2019) for the three dates for each company.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  From what you describe `WHERE` seems sufficient for the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing a `where` clause with `or`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (company = :comp1 and date = :date1) or
      (company = :comp2 and date = :date2) or
      . . .
```

Comment: If you had 1 million companies, what then?

Comment: @ewfe . . . I would put them in a table and use `join`.

Comment: Seems kind of a silly hack. Is SQL really this inflexible? My question was so basic lol, you'd think there's just be one simple command.

Comment: @ewfe . . . `WHERE` with parameters is not a "hack".  This is how SQL works.

Comment: So you'd write WHERE 1 million times for each of the conditions?

Comment: @ewfe . . . I already answered that question.  I would put the data in a table.

Comment: And I already said that's an inflexible way of doing something so simple. Also, what's with the DOT DOT DOT? Seems rude.